# Do I have to implement Add/Delete methods in my NHibernate entities?

Tags: nhibernate, methods, entity, addition

This is a sample from the Fluent NHibernate website:

Compared to the Entitiy Framework I have ADD methods in my POCO in this code sample using NHibernate. With the EF I did context.Add or context.AddObject etc... the context had the methods to put one entity into the others entity collection!

Do I really have to implement Add/Delete/Update methods (I do not mean the real database CRUD operations!) in a NHibernate entity ?

```
public class Store
{
  public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; set; }

  public Store()
  {
    Products = new List<Product>();
    Staff = new List<Employee>();
  }

  public virtual void AddProduct(Product product)
  {
    product.StoresStockedIn.Add(this);
    Products.Add(product);
  }

  public virtual void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
  {
    employee.Store = this;
    Staff.Add(employee);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do this for nhibernate, you have to do this for keep in-memory consistence and not repeat yourself.

**Consistence in memory**

If you have a two way relationship, lets say Order has Lines, and Line as a relationship to order. You don't want to have a reference from one side and not from the other. 
If you just do:

```
order.Lines.Add(line);
```

You have made a reference from Order to Line, but Line.Order property remains null. So your in-memory instances are not consistent.

**Don't Repeat Yourself**

You can use the following code :
order.Lines.Add(line);
line.Order = order;

but you will be repeating yourself, so it is better to put this code in only one place, and the best place is as order.AddLine(..).

Comment: é YES if I would do only order.Lines.Add(line); it would be a 1:N relation. Do I assume right then that I should use the AddXXX methods in a entity with a Many to Many relation => product.StoresStockedIn.Add(this);
    Products.Add(product); These both code lines create a reference from every side. The question is now is it not depending on my requirements wether i create 2 references. Maybe I query all Orders with its Lines, but I never access the Order list inside a Line object which is Null as you said. Then I could save the 2nd step or save that AddXXX methods at all, right?

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to.  You could just call `SomeStore.Products.Add(someProduct)` directly from outside of your entity.  But it's often good practice to make the collections 'read-only' from a public perspective, and using an add method in the entity for adding items.

One benefit of this is that you can put additional logic in there. For instance in your store example, you could set a 'storesStockedIn' collection (if there was such a thing) in the same method, and so keep all the logic about to creating that relationship in one place.

This isn't really a NHibernate thing, but rather an OOP thing.  (Although I'm not familiar with EF - maybe it automates some of this for you).  The design decisions are exactly the same as if it was just an unpersisted poco (without NHibernate).

Comment: ah... I was blind store.Products.Add(...) stupid me ;-) so yes as you said the additional add method is just for doing extra wanted stuff. BUT then the author of that code sample should have made the setter of Products IList PRIVATE so I would have immediately known I should use the extra Add method, its just confusing to have 2 Add methods...

Comment: like this: public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; private set; }
        public virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; private set; }

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it's not that easy to hide it.  That just stops you replacing the whole Products list - I'm pretty sure you'll still be able to use the implicit .Add() on the collection, even though the setter for the collection is private.